# Swift Error Message on xCode7.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7.3

I have just started learning xCode7.3 and I am getting an error code but not sure what I am doing wrong.. It is very simple and just want to change the title on a UIButton when it is pressed. I have set it to IBAction func and have typed into the code:

```
makeItBlueButton.setTitle("It is Blue", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

It then comes up with error code stating that Static member 'Normal' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIControlState'. This confuses me. If I leave it without a full stop after UIControlState it suggests I put a comma in there but when I do, it just states Use of unresolved identifier 'Normal'.

Can anyone help???

Comment: Thanks - that was a typo on my behalf as I did have it like that. See response below. Sorry for such a lame question but this is doing my head in! :)

Comment: where can I find Code Completion please? Thanks

Comment: Type a few characters and Xcode will show the completion or press the escape key

Answer (score 0):

Your are not invoking the function correctly, try this:

```
myButton.setTitle("It is blue", forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Sorry - my bad... that is what I have done.  The actual line I've written is: makeItBlueButton.setTitle("It is Blue", forState: UIControlState.Normal) after setting an IBOutlet weak var makeItBlueButton: UIButton. I have literally copied it from the tutorial but still the same error....

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to an enum value, Swift already knows the type so you just say which enumerated option you're going for. So:

```
makeItBlueButton.setTitle("It is Blue", forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: You can omit the type, but you don't have to. Also `UIControlState` is not an enum, but `OptionSetType` - it works kind of like a bitmask, you can pass multiple values in array, e.g. `[.Selected, .Highlighted]` and set title or any other property for cases where control is in both states simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple. Try this one. Two ways to do this:

If you have both Outlet and IBAction of this button defined. Then

```
@IBOutlet weak var makeItBlueButtonOutlet: UIButton!

@IBAction func makeItBlueButton(sender: AnyObject) {
         makeItBlueButtonOutlet.setTitle("It is blue", forState: .Normal)   
}
```

If only IBAction is defined then.

```
@IBAction func makeItBlueButton(sender: AnyObject) {
         sender.setTitle("It is blue", forState: .Normal)   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same exact error:

> "Static member 'Normal' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIControlState'."

After hours of trying to figure out and modifying the code found out that when I typed `UIControlState`, I selected the first option from the list of values. Instead, when I selected the second `UIControlState` from the list of values, for some reason it *stopped giving me the error* and started to Build Successfully.

It's dumb and could not explain why? But it worked...